Hillshade not working in QGIS 3.34.14
When I run Hillshade I get the following error.  I have run Hillsade on this file with an earlier version of QGIS and it worked fine.
/Applications/QGIS-LTR 2.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/gdaldem: line 3: /Applications/QGIS-LTR: No such file or directory
Process returned error code 127
Execution completed in 0.11 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': '/Users/michaelsharpe/Documents/Science and '
'Technology/ARCHAEOLOGY/Scotland/Moray/Findhorn Dunes Site/Maps, '
'mine/FDsites QGIS map/QGIS files/Hillshade/Hillshade 30,30.tif'}
Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• /Users/michaelsharpe/Documents/Science and Technology/ARCHAEOLOGY/Scotland/Moray/Findhorn Dunes Site/Maps, mine/FDsites QGIS map/QGIS files/Hillshade/Hillshade 30,30.tif
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.

I discovered that my OS had renamed the new version of QGIS (3.34)as LTR 2 since the old version was still in the Apps folder, and this meant that algorithms like Hillshade could not find the app Contents folder. Once I renamed the App by deleting the 2, it worked fine.  Simple housekeeping!
